{% static 'file' %} should fail if file not present
I am currently working on a Django application. When I use {% static 'file' %} within my template everything works great locally and on production as well, when file exists.
When file does not exist, the error only occurs in production; collectstatic also seems to ignore that the file does not exist. I get a 500 when trying to get the start page.
I would like this error to also occur in development mode. Did I misconfigure Django and it would normally do that? Or can it at least be configured that way?
Just giving me the error page in development mode with the incorrect file path would be perfect.

Do you have Debug set as True in your settings.py?

Also why would you refer to a non-existent static file in your code? Are you testing something?

@16171413 I do not want to set a filename that does not exist, but it just happened to me and I only caught it on a test stage that deploys the app in production mode. I would like to find the typo way earlier. Also: setting Debug to True or False does not change anything about the behaviour sadly. I have it set to True normally.

Remember your HTML files are not translated as HTML is not a programming language. So getting an error message for a non-existent file might require some workaround.

@16171413 But these are templates where django replaces {% static 'file' %} with a url, so it should check if the file exists also in development mode I would think.

So can you clarify, if the file does not exist, do you get to see it in development but not in production? Or is it that there's no error message in development but a 500 error in production?

@16171413 the second, as the file does not exist it is also not there in development.  I had to fix up a project that is broken and it had some dead static file references which were never found because it was never rolled out onto production. They are there probably because someone copy pasted them there without much thought. That is why I would like there to be an error for them. Removing one of them, then building and rolling out to the test stage and repeating that x times is a tedious process depending on the size of x of course.

Ensure that Debug is True in your settings.py. It will usually show a missing static file error.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
